# Representation of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: group-theory, modules, representation-theory

> Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $2$. Let $V$ be a finite dimension $k$-vector space and 
>   $$\rho: \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to{\rm Aut}_k(V)$$
>   a representation of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}=\{1,\sigma\}$ over $k$. Show that $V$ can be decomposed as $W_1 \oplus W_2$ where $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of $V$, moreover $W_2$ can be decomposed as a direct sum of subspaces $U_i$ of dimension $2$ so that $\sigma$ acts on $W_1$ as indentity and acts on $U_i$ as follows: there exists a basis $x_i,y_i$ of $U_i$ so that $\sigma(x_i)=x_i$ and $\sigma(y_i)=y_i+x_i$.

My wrong attempt (thanks @Omnomnomnom for the comment): We have $\rho(\sigma)^2=\rho(\sigma^2)=Id$, i.e $\rho(\sigma)=f$ is an idempotent element in ${\rm End}(V)$. Hence, we can decompose $V={\rm im}(f)\oplus {\rm im}(1-f)$. However, I cannot prove the latter part of the problem.

P/s: By [Maschke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem): Every representation of a finite group $G$ over a field $F$ with characteristic not dividing the order of $G$ is a direct sum of irreducible representations. However, the hypothesis of the problem does not satisfy the condition of this theorem.

Comment: What are the $U_i$?

Comment: I have edited. Thanks

Comment: Also, your note is incorrect: $f$ satisfying $f^2 = I$ does not make it idempotent; your division assumes that $f^2 = f$.  Note that if $k$ had characteristic not equal to $2$, then we could take advantage of the fact that $\frac 12 (f + I)$ would necessarily be idempotent to produce an analogous decomposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The statement to be proven is equivalent to saying that there exists a basis relative to which the matrix of $\rho(\sigma)$ is given by
$$
M = \pmatrix{I\\ &A\\ && \ddots \\ &&& A}
$$
where $I$ denotes an identity matrix of some size, and 
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\1&1}.
$$
Note in particular that $M$ is in [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form).

You might find it informative to consider the representation $\rho:G \to k^n$ for which $\rho(\sigma) = M$.  Note that in this case, we would have $x_i = e_{2j-1},y_i = e_{2j}$ for some index $j$, where $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denotes the standard basis of $k^n$.

---

**Hint:** Note that $\rho(\sigma)^2 + I = 0$.  Thus, the minimal polynomial $m \in k[x]$ of $\rho(\sigma)$ must divide
$$
x^2 + 1 = (x - 1)^2.
$$
What does this let you deduce about the Jordan form of $\rho(\sigma)$?  It now suffices to show that there exist a choice of basis of $V$ over $k$ (rather than over the algebraic completion $\bar k$) relative to which $\rho(\sigma)$ has the form of $M$.

Alternatively, we can skirt the issue of algebraic completions if we stick to the [Frobenius normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form).  In particular, note that the matrix $M$ above is similar to
$$
\tilde M = \pmatrix{I \\ & C \\ && \ddots \\ &&& C}
$$
where $A$ is as defined above, and $C$ is the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) to the polynomial $x^2 + 1$.  This holds because $A$ is similar to $C$.

The fact that $\rho(\sigma)$ must have the matrix $\tilde M$ relative to some basis is a direct consequence of the [structure theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain).

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I have understood your hint. Can you explain in more detail how obtain the matrix?

Comment: See my latest edit.